# How can I check if elements and roots of two different XML files are the same (using c#)

Tags: c#, xml

I have loaded 2 xml files in c#, but I want to know how I can compare the nodes, elements and attributes in both of the files without writing a blob of code.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use Beyond Compare on the files.

Comment: Is there any other way except using Beyond Compare?

Comment: The question is what are you planning to do with the differences?  Do you need automated results?  What are your requirements?

Comment: My plan is to create a new XML file and store the automated results there and possibly overwrite/update it if new data appears.

Comment: You probably have to write the code.  There are not libraries that will do exactly what you want.

Comment: `I have loaded` - how did you load? What did you use: XElement, XmlDocument, some Serializer?

Comment: Look at [XNode.DeepEquals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals?view=net-6.0).

Comment: I used XDocument